# Excel - Time formula - between

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

My formula does not work. I have a time in and time out. I want a formula that will tell me if the employee will be there during that time.

Below is my formula

```
=IF(AND(C2>=$D$16,C2<$E$16),"Yes","No")
```

I want a formula to be able to give me the result in the attached picture.

Thank you for your help.
[Spreadsheet Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDnvL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MEDIAN(starttime, endtime, time)` like this:

```
=IF(C2=MEDIAN($D$16,$E$16,C2),"Yes","No")
```

In this example, `C2` is the cell with the time you wish to examine.